# How to create circle gradient in Final Cut Pro?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, color-grading, mask

I'm starting out with Final Cut Pro and I want to create a circular gradient to white in Final Cut Pro so that the movie looks like the image below.

I searched around and found a Graduated Mask effect. That is only a linear effect though, and it does a gradient to black (and I can't find a setting to change the color).

Does anybody know how I can do this in Final Cut Pro X? All tips are welcome!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a new custom generator and set the colour to white.

   [image]
2. Add your media above. In this example, I will use a photo.
3. Apply the Draw Mask to your image.
4. Click to add 4 control points, then set the control point positions using the inspector.

   [image]
5. Choose B-Spline as the Shape Type, then set the Feather and Falloff as appropriate.

   [image]